# ¿Es posible guardar las huellas digitales de varios usuarios en sqlite en android?

Tags: android

mi duda es si existe algún método con el cual pueda usar el sensor de huellas dactilares de cualquier celular de android y guardar los datos en una base de datos de sqlite usando Android Studio.

Comment: No. Por razones de seguridad no se puede acceder a la información de las huellas. El procesamiento es entre el hardware y el sistema operativo.

Comment: Cuales datos de la huella dactilar piensas guardar o de que forma?

Comment: Pensaba usar el hardware del celular (lector de huella digital) en lugar de comprar un hardware externo, ya que el lector de huellas digitales de los celulares viene con un número límitado de huellas que puedes guardar en el dispositivo, por lo que pensaba usar una base de datos sql lite para guardar una mayor cantidad de huellas.